# Discrepancies between Google Data API (GA4) and WebUI

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

When fetching data from the Google Analytics 4 (GA4) Data API using Python, the numbers obtained differ significantly from those displayed on the Google Analytics WebUI. Specifically, discrepancies are observed when comparing the metrics for "active users" across different channel groups.

For example:
For date range Sep 11 - Sep 17, 2023:
In the GA4 WebUI, the "Direct" channel group shows 17230 active users.
Using the GA4 Data API, the "Direct" channel group indicates only 24007 active users.

The code is designed to fetch GA4 data for a specific property, date range, dimensions, and metrics. It utilizes the BetaAnalyticsDataClient for API access. The dimensions fetched include defaultChannelGroup, pagePath, country, and date. The metrics retrieved are activeUsers and totalUsers.

Sample Code for Fetching Data:

```
def ga4_get_report_df(property_id):
    try:
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
        client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient(credentials=credentials)
        offset = 0
        limit = 250000
        data = []
        start_date = '2023-01-01'

        while True:
            request = RunReportRequest(
                property=f'properties/{property_id}',
                date_ranges=[
                    DateRange(start_date=start_date, end_date='yesterday')
                ],
                dimensions=[
                    Dimension(name='defaultChannelGroup'),
                    Dimension(name='pagePath'),
                    Dimension(name='country'),
                    Dimension(name='date')
                ],
                metrics=[
                    Metric(name='activeUsers'),
                    Metric(name='totalUsers')
                ],
                limit=limit,
                offset=offset
            )

            response = client.run_report(request)
            df = ga4_response_to_df(response)
            df = process_data(df)
            data.append(df)
            offset += limit
            logger.info(f'Page done. Starting with offset {offset}')

            if len(df) < limit:
                break

        df = pd.concat(data)

        return df
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error retrieving GA4 data: {str(e)}")
        raise
```

Sample Code for Converting to DataFrame:

```
def ga4_response_to_df(api_response):
    dimension_headers = [header.name for header in api_response.dimension_headers]
    metric_headers = [header.name for header in api_response.metric_headers]
    dimensions = []
    metrics = []
    for i in range(len(dimension_headers)):
        dimensions.append([row.dimension_values[i].value for row in api_response.rows])

    for i in range(len(metric_headers)):
        metrics.append([row.metric_values[i].value for row in api_response.rows])
    headers = dimension_headers, metric_headers
    headers = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(headers))   
    data = dimensions, metrics
    data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.transpose()
    df.columns = headers
    return df

def format_data(df):
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    #df['user_engagement_duration'] = df['user_engagement_duration'].astype(int)
    df['active_users'] = df['active_users'].astype(int)
    df['total_users'] = df['total_users'].astype(int)
    #df['avg_engagement_duration_sec'] = df['user_engagement_duration'] / df['active_users']
    return df


def format_column_names(df):
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('([A-Z])', r'_\1', regex=True).tolist()
    df.columns = [col.lstrip('_') for col in df.columns]
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
    return df
```

The data is loaded in a database afterwards.

[Screenshot UI report and API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIwI2.jpg)

What could be the reason for this discrepancy, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: You are comparing two different reports the results will not be the same.   This is not a programing issue this is an understanding analytics issue.   Remove the extra dimensions and metrics and try again.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Ok nice thank you, that helped! But shouldn't the data be consistent? Can you direct me to an explanation?

Comment: Google analytics is a multi dimension database,  not a relation database.   Its only going to be consistent if you are running the same report.   If you add additional metrics or dimensions its like comparing apples to oranges.  They arnt based upon the same data so the results will not be the same.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I see, thank you kindly.